# Promote index to primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table in a MariaDB database for which no primary key is defined. However, it has an index. I'd like to add a primary key with the same definition as that index. The naïve way might be:

```
alter table `foo` add primary key (`bar`, `baz`),
                  drop index `qux`;
```

...but that will take a very long time and seems wasteful. (The table is tens of gigabytes in size and is running on a machine with less free disk space than the total size of the table.) I realize an index and a primary key aren't the same thing (at the very least, the primary key includes a uniqueness constraint which must be checked during the creation process), but is there any way to use the index to “bootstrap” the primary key?

Comment: Is `qux` the 'name' of the index on `(bar, baz)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table is `ENGINE=InnoDB`??...

If there is not enough free space on disk for another copy of the table, the task cannot be performed without the help of a second server.  Can you drop some tables?  Or otherwise free up space?

A `PRIMARY KEY` is `UNIQUE` and is an index.  If the combination of `bar` and `baz` is not unique, you should not turn it into the PK.

Using a PK for looking up a single row is faster than using a secondary index.  This is because it first looks up the row in the secondary index's BTree.  There it finds the `PRIMARY KEY`, which is then used to find the row in the data's BTree.

If the table is bigger than `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, your change would also (in many cases) eliminate a disk hit.  (Disk hits are the slowest part of database operations.)

Yes, there is currently a `PRIMARY KEY` on you table.  It is a 6-byte hidden 'column'.  Your `ALTER` would throw that away, thereby making the table a little smaller (another small benefit).

Do you have `innodb_file_per_table=ON` (or =1)?  If the table is in its own .ibd file, you will recover the disk space after the operation (assuming it can run at all).  With `OFF`, it will increase the size of the `ibdata1` file, but fail to shrink it back.  *Have it `ON` when creating tables that will eventually be 'big'.*

OK, there *may* be hope.  If you are running with `OFF`, *and* there is enough space in `ibdata1`, then the task may complete.  (But that means, as aluded to above, that you have already bloated ibdata1.)